# Add a blockstyle to RTE

Tags: typo3, rte, typo3-7.6.x

I try to add a own blockstyle to the RTE. Here is my pageTS (in the rootpage):

```
RTE.default.proc {
    allowedClasses := addToList(texttwocolumn)
    entryHTMLparser_db.allowedClasses < .allowedClasses
}

lib.parseFunc_RTE.allowedClasses := addToList(texttwocolumn)

RTE.default.buttons.blockstyle.tags {
    p.allowedClasses := addToList(texttwocolumn)
    div.allowedClasses := addToList(texttwocolumn)
}
 RTE.classes.texttwocolumn { 
     name = Two Column
 }
```

With this config I can manually add the class `texttwocolumn` in the HTML and it keeps it when I save it. But I can not select it in the blockstyle selectbox. With this config it even removes all the other blockstyles.

I tried to copy the config from different tutorials and stackoverflow answers but it seems I miss something. Typo3 Version is 7.6.4 and version of rtehtmlarea is 7.6.0

Comment: Have you defined the style in your RTE css file?

Comment: @sven No I have not cause I do not need to see the style in the backend and for the frontend it is defined in another css file already. I will add a RTE css file right now and check if this change something.

Comment: @sven I added a css with: `.texttwocolumn { background: red }` to test it. Now `div` or `p` in the RTE with this class have a red background, but the Block style is still `Unknown block style`.